# Delete confirmation passes wrong user id in laravel, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want that implement delete confirmation in laravel app when click on delete button. it works fine if there is no confirm dialoge, but does not work when I add javascript confirmation code.

here is my blade file

```
   <a href="{{ route('user.destroy', $user->id)}}" class="dropdown-item" onclick="
        var result = confirm('are you sure delete this?');
        if (result) {
            document.getElementById('delete_user').submit();
        }
        event.preventDefault();

        "><i class="icon-bin text-danger"></i> Delete</a>

      <form id="delete_user" action="{{ route('user.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="POST">
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
      </form>
```

Comment: I'm betting you have multiple forms with the same ID (generated in a loop) here. Get rid of the link. Use a real submit button inside the form instead. Use the onsubmit event of the form for your "Are you sure?" check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a form using native `onsubmit` function.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.destroy', ['user' => $user])}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display: inline" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure wanted to delete it?')">
      @method('DELETE')
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn btn-sm">
          Delete
      </button>
    </form>
```

I have been using it for may of my Projects its working fine for me. Can you try it.

And I have tried to find the bug in your code and i sorted it out.

when you add `delete_user` to the form and refer those id in `a` tag `id` of form need to be unique otherwise it will delete the delete the wrong record so I have fixed it by adding `id` (id of each record) like this `delete_user_{{$user->id}}`

so here is your code with bug fix.

```
<a href="{{ route('user.destroy', ['user' => $user])}}" class="dropdown-item" onclick="
      var result = confirm('are you sure delete this?');
      if (result) {
          document.getElementById('delete_user_{{$user->id}}').submit();
      }
      event.preventDefault();

      "><i class="icon-bin text-danger"></i> Delete</a>

    <form id="delete_user_{{$user->id}}" action="{{ route('user.destroy', ['user' => $user]) }}" method="POST">
      @method('DELETE')
      @csrf
    </form>
```

If you face any issues kindly comment below

Answer (score -1):

Remove `href` attribute from `<a>`. And also onclick must be function.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="deleteUser(event)"><i class="icon-bin text-danger"></i> Delete</a>
```

Define delete function in the bottom of file.

```
<script>
function deleteUser(event){
  var result = confirm('are you sure delete this?');
  if (result) {
     document.getElementById('delete_user').submit();
  }
  event.preventDefault();

}
</script>
```

Comment: The `href` doesn't make the browser navigate to the link at the same time as the form is submitted because the JavaScript always called `preventDefault`. Removing it just prevents assistive technology from recognising that it is something the user can click on.

Comment: Putting a function in the `onclick` function body means that clicking on it will run the function expression to *define* a function but then *never call it* which makes it completely pointless.

Comment: I'm suggesting to remove href attribute, because it is not necessary, about `function`, you are right, will edit my post.

Comment: I just explained why removing the `href` attribute makes the code worse without solving the problem. It is necessary (at least with this hacky implementation that should just be a submit button).

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work. thanks for your answer.